# Label text is overlapping in Donut Series of RadHtmlChart

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radhtmlchart

I have a radhtmlchart with donut series. I displays different values in labels but text of labels get overlap and does not read properly.

[image]

This is my code:

```
<telerik:DonutSeries Name="Transactions" DataFieldY="Transactions" 
                     NameField="Name" ColorField="ColorValue">
    <LabelsAppearance Visible="true" DataFormatString="{0}%" Position="Column">
    </LabelsAppearance>
</telerik:DonutSeries>
```

Comment: Did you try calling the FixAxisLabelsOverlapping() method on your radhtmlchart

Comment: no. I could not find any such method for radhtmlchart. Can you share any link or info for this ?

Answer (score 0):

`Column` is an invalid value for the `Position` property, use one of the valid ones (see **List 2** here: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/htmlchart/server-side-programming/series-configuration#attribute-properties-in-seriestype--labelsappearance)

http://screencast.com/t/M4FK0kA5 is what I get from

```
<telerik:RadHtmlChart runat="server" ID="rhc1" Width="500px" Height="500px">
    <PlotArea>
        <Series>
            <telerik:DonutSeries Name="Transactions" DataFieldY="Transactions"
                NameField="Name">
                <LabelsAppearance Visible="true" DataFormatString="{0}%" Position="OutsideEnd">
                </LabelsAppearance>
            </telerik:DonutSeries>
        </Series>
    </PlotArea>
</telerik:RadHtmlChart>
```